# Столбец Rap не существует! postgreSQL! Постоянно выбивает эту ошибку при попытке занести инфу

Tags: python, postgresql

import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://ssvt:qqq@localhost:5432/hw')

connection = engine.connect()

add_new = connection.execute("""INSERT INTO genre(id,genre_name) VALUES(1,rap)""")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вставить переменную с именем rap которая нигде не определена, а не какое-то значение.

```
connection.execute("""INSERT INTO genre(id,genre_name) VALUES(1,rap)""")
```

Необходимо rap взять в кавычки:

```
connection.execute("""INSERT INTO genre(id,genre_name) VALUES(1,'rap')""")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)